# Why should I choose 几乎 over 将近？

Tags: meaning

I had this 填空。

我国与其他国家_____ 同时起步，在这一项目上有一定的实力。

I could choose  似乎，几乎，将近，曾经

I can't see much difference between 几乎 and 将近， I am told 几乎 is correct.

I there a definite, palpable reason for this?

Comment: 将近 is 即将接近 (现代汉语词典 says `（时间、数量等）快要接近`). Thus the reason is about the tense: 将近 is "**will** be close to some quantity, time point, etc., in the very near future".

Comment: however iciba also has examples with ＂in the very near future＂somewhat doubtful： 2001年9月11日,将近3000人丧生于基地分子之手.将近四分之一的英国总体碳排量来自于道路运输.全世界范围内,每年有将近4万人死于恶性黑素瘤.more at iciba，maybe 同时 in the present example makes a difference

Comment: which textbook has this 填空? some users would like to find the place in the book showing the need for 几乎.

Comment: Reechen, das ist 卓越汉语致胜5 fltrp Seite22 
Ich denke 差不多 = 几乎，但是，也可以在你上面的句子写‘差不多3000人。Ask an Englishman what is the difference between 'almost' and 'nearly'

Answer (score 2):

> 我国与其他国家_____ 同时起步，在这一项目上有一定的实力。

让我来试试解释一下这道填空题，这几个选项“*似乎，几乎，将近，曾经*”主要用作修饰**同时**，如果我们不填任何选项，那么这句话也是完整的，是一个(因为...所以...)句型，

> **因为**我国与其他国家同时起步，**所以**在这一项目上有一定的实力。

*几乎* - 表示差不多的意思。基本上来讲，'几乎同时'也就是'同时'的意思。所以下面这句话读起来没问题，

> **因为**我国与其他国家**几乎**同时起步，**所以**在这一项目上有一定的实力。

*将近* - 表示快要的意思。'将近同时'离'同时'还有一段距离，还未赶上其他国家。所以下面这句话读起来不符合逻辑，还未赶上人家，怎么就有一定的实力了？

> **因为**我国与其他国家**将近**同时起步，**所以**在这一项目上有一定的实力。

*似乎* - 表示看起来像的意思。'似乎同时'表示不肯定，所以下面这句话也是有问题的，不肯定是不是同时起步，怎么就有一定的实力了？

> **因为**我国与其他国家**似乎**同时起步，**所以**在这一项目上有一定的实力。

*曾经* - 表示以前的意思。'以前同时'起步，也有可能没赶上，所以不一定有实力。下面这句话也是有问题的，

> **因为**我国与其他国家**曾经**同时起步，**所以**在这一项目上有一定的实力。

I will try to add English version later ...

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but you should know that you need to work on your English.

Comment: Users resent being lectured by some other user. 有使用者憎恶受到别使用者的教训.

Comment: But if user informs user user's use of English is misuse, this is well meant.

Comment: @S.Rhee Sorry, I do not want educate anyone, the answer looks so blunt due to my English is not good. :)

Comment: @Pedroski Could you please also indicate my error in my comment, I will be able to improve my English.

Comment: @peterwang You can write the answer in both languages so people can understand your intended meaning by reading the Chinese version and help you improve the English version.

Comment: So, there want to describe the project in our country starting almost at the same time with another country in the past, nearly looks the project in our country still not starting.

My guess at your meaning: So, that sentence means to say that a project started in our country at almost the same time as it did in other countries, however, in comparison, it seems as if my country has only just begun.
Hope that helps. Linux rules!Yeah!

Comment: users welcome being educated by experts on Chinese，but resent being lectured by people whose own English is defective on English language use。This does not mean they do not welcome corrections of translations。 大多数使用者欣然接受汉语传家的教学，而憎恶受到讲缺陷英语人之关于英语的训斥，这并不意味着使用者不欣然接受其翻译的修改。

Comment: 可能可敬的user's useful use of English unusually has an error of use. User may consider using 'resent being lectured by people whose own English is defective when they use it.

Comment: @Pedroski Thank you very much for your help！

Answer (score 1):

将近 is used in conjunction with an amount or a time point, but not with another entity with the same attribute. See the following examples:

- 她短短一个月突然暴瘦到将近 80 斤。(Correct! "80 斤" is an amount)
- 他一直工作到深夜将近 1 点。(Correct! "1 点" is a time point)
- 我和他将近一样高。(Wrong! "他" is neither an amount nor a time point, but another entity. Should use 几乎 here)

Comment: It seems 将近于 could be used without an amount or a time point：他将近于死,灵魂要走的时候,就给他儿子起名叫便俄尼;他父亲却给他起名叫便雅悯。As she （他） breathed her last-for she was dying-she named her son Ben-Oni. But his father named him Benjamin.

Comment: Your example is also a time point (at the time of his death). Using 将近 here is correct, although I'd say the whole sentence doesn't sound quite natural. You just can't use 将近 to compare two entities with one common attribute. For example, 他和他的妻子将近同时死的 is wrong.

Comment: comment has 将近于 not 将近.

Comment: 于 means "at". 将近于 is "almost at".

Comment: the question is whether 将近于同时 might be correct, although
without 于 it may not be, if 于 is put in front of the activity it may become a time point, thus 于死 may have changed 死 to a time point, and therefore 将近于死 is acceptable

Comment: 她短短一个月突然暴瘦到将近 80 斤。is also good with 几乎
他一直工作到深夜将近 1 点。ditto
我和他将近一样高。(Wrong! Concur。
Any idea why?